# How to use BigInteger in VS 2010

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, numerical-methods

I have been trying to use the BigInteger type, that is supposedly new in .NET Framework 4.0.

I don't seem to be able to get to it, and get an error when trying to reference it via Using System.Numerics.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Sorry if this is a stupid question...

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. [Add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=VS.100).aspx) to the *System.Numerics* assembly to your project.

   a. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project node and click **Add Reference**.

   b. In the **Add Reference** dialog box, select the **.NET** tab.

   c. Select **System.Numerics**, and then click **OK**.
2. Add a [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) importing the *System.Numerics* namespace:

   ```
   using System.Numerics;
   ```
3. Use the [BigInteger structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx):

   ```
   var i = new BigInteger(934157136952);
   ```

Comment: @Bradley: Makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

Did you add a reference to System.Numerics?

> Right click on References -> Add Reference -> .NET tab -> System.Numerics -> OK

Answer (score 1):

Add a Reference to System.Numerics assembly.

Add `using System.Numerics;` statement

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a project reference (Project... Add Reference...) to System.Numerics?