# Unity3D - C# The name 'BigInteger' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, biginteger

I do not understand why I get error on the line `BigInteger a = new BigInteger(25);`

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Numerics;

public class Variabili : MonoBehaviour {

    BigInteger a = new BigInteger(25);

    public static ulong atomi;
    public static float tempoDiGIoco = 0;

    public static float metri = 0;
    public static float kilometri = 0;
    public static float anniluce = 0;

    public static float prestige = 1.00f;

}
```

[image]

Comment: If you type in `System.Numerics.` and wait for Intellisense to kick in, what suggestions do you get?

Comment: sorry but I don't understand what you're talking :). I would simply create a huge variable that can hold up to 10 ^ 50. and I saw on the internet that serves a BigInteger but I can not implement it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use BigInteger in VS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281858/how-to-use-biginteger-in-vs-2010)

Comment: I'm suggesting that somewhere in your code, e.g. in a method, you type in `System.Numerics.` (including the trailing dot) and see what happens. Do you get any prompts? Do you currently have an error for your `using System.Numerics;` line?

Comment: happen this Assets/Scripts/Variabili.cs(3,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Numerics' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: Nothing happens if you put a . after Numerics

Comment: You are then missing the reference to System.Numerics on your VS project. If you remove the big integer line form code, does the project compile (without removing the using clause)?

Comment: no. I get the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Mono version which is an equivalent of .NET 3.5, but the System.Numerics is available in [.NET 4.0+ only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.100).aspx).

I'm afraid that you [have to add a third party library](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/355810/bigintegerbigrational.html) to your project.

Unity3d [doesn't have](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/890835/biginteger-in-unity3d.html) BigInteger implementation.

This one: [biginteger.codeplex.com](http://biginteger.codeplex.com/) should be fine.