# Factorial function for 100 results 0 in c# even though using long type

Tags: c#, factorial

I have this code to determine factorial of 100. But after fifties it starts giving result of 0. I looked for answers for this problem and the common saying was using long variable. But even though using it, it still says that the answer is 0. Can you tell me where I am making mistake ?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long c;
        int a = 100;
        c = a * (a - 1);
        for (int i=a-2; i>=1 ; i--)
        {
            c = c * i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(c);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }`
```

Comment: 100! has 157+ digits. A `long` isn't big enough to hold that. In a 64-bit value you get 18 or 19 digits. 128 bits will get you ~38 digits.

Comment: [100 factorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=100!) does not fit in a long.

Comment: You cannot go higher than 49, otherwise, you will get a number that is larger than a long type.

Comment: Try [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of `long`.

Comment: The factorial for 100 is approx. 9.3E157, whereas the max value for long is 9.2E18. So it’s way over the limit of the data type. You should try the BigInteger datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`long` type isn't long enough to store the factorial of 100.

Use `BigInteger` instead:

```
BigInteger c = new BigInteger(0);
int a = 100;
c = a * (a - 1);
for (int i = a - 2; i >= 1; i--)
{
    c = c * i;
}
Console.WriteLine(c);
Console.ReadLine();
```

In order to use `BigInteger` you have to add a reference to the System.Numerics assembly to your project. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281858/how-to-use-biginteger-in-vs-2010))